# sort value of a map by comparator with java streams api

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Map` and want to sort the values by a `Comparator` putting the result into a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
Map<String, User> sorted = test.getUsers()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(SORT_BY_NAME))
                .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (map, entry) -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()),
                        LinkedHashMap::putAll);
test.setUsers(sorted);
```

**All works, however, I wonder if this can be simplified.**

Actually I create a new `Map` and put that new `Map` into the `setUsers()`. Can I change the stream directly without creating a new `LinkedHashMap`?

With `Collections.sort(Comparator)`, the list is directly sorted. However, `Collections.sort` does not work with Maps.

Comment: @LeoAso It's not really possible to sort a map in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform in-place sorting on a collection that does not support array-style indexing, so for maps it is out of the question (except you use something like selection sort on a `LinkedHashMap`, but that would be a bad idea). Creating a new map is unavoidable. You can still simplify it though, by following shmosel's answer.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about "in place sorting" of a Map. Good to know that this is actually impossible with java streams.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `Collectors.toMap()`?

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Entry::getKey,
        Entry::getValue,
        (a, b) -> { throw new AssertionError("impossible"); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: I dont like to put `(a, b) -> { throw new AssertionError("impossible"); },'`. Java does not allow only to use `Collectors.toMap(
        Entry::getKey,
        Entry::getValue,
        LinkedHashMap::new)`..

Comment: I know, it sucks. If you're going for brevity, you can do `(a, b) -> a`.